# Is there a delay to show Total Rep on Area 51 proposals?

Tags: support, area-51

I finally hit over 200 rep on a Stack Overflow site!  ::cheering fans::

That gave me the +100 rep bonus on all my other SO sites ::more cheering::

However, on my accounts page on Area 51, those bonuses don't show in the rep count, nor on the Total Rep number for proposals I've committed to.

Is there a delay in posting these rep gains?  Or is this a possible bug?

Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I did try to unassociate and reassociate all the sites.  No change.

Comment: How long have you waited?

Comment: At this point, it's been about an hour. I didn't know if this was a batch process, immediate process, or a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a delay -- we only pull in your latest rep totals nightly.  If it's still not showing up tomorrow, we have a bug.

Also, congrats :)